# @Reflect.metadata generates error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7, reflect-metadata

I tried to apply the `@Reflect.metadata` decorator to a TypeScript class, following the example on lines 82-84 of [reflect-metadata.d.ts](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators/blob/master/reflect-metadata.d.ts):

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata.d.ts"/>

@Reflect.metadata('key', 0)
class C {
}
```

However, the TypeScript 1.7.2 compiler generates the following error on the `@Reflect.metadata` line:

> error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
>   Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the TypeScript [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#decorators-are-checked-as-call-expressions):

> Decorators are checked as call expressions
>
> Starting with 1.6, decorators type checking is more accurate; **the compiler will checks a decorator expression as a call expression** with the decorated entity as a parameter. This can cause error to be reported that were not in previous releases.

My guess is that you probably need to **use a newer version of TypeScript or an older version of `reflect-metadata`.**

The latest releases are:

- `typescript@2.3.2`
- `reflect-metadata@0.1.10`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to mark all of the decorator function's arguments as optional:

```js
function logType(a?: any, b?: any) {
    console.log(a, b);
}

@logType
class MyClass {...}
```

and then adjust them according to your needs.